# Moq saying 0 calls when it lists a call?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I have a unit test that is using Moq to mock interfaces and verify calls.  Here is the test code:

```
[Fact]
public void NewBlank_InvokesManagerAdd()
{
    // ReSharper disable once AssignNullToNotNullAttribute
    var newPath = Path.Combine(_testSaveDirectory, "InvokeBlank.txt");

    _dbManagerMock.Setup(manager => manager.KeynoteDBs).Returns(new ObservableCollection<KeynoteDBVM>());
    _dialogMock.Setup(dialog => dialog.GetSaveFileDialogResult(It.IsAny<SaveFileDialogData>()))
               .Returns(newPath);

    _commands.CmdNewBlank.Execute(null);

    _dbManagerMock
        .Verify(manager => manager.AddDB(It.IsAny<KeynoteDB>(), It.IsAny<int>()),
                Times.Once);
}
```

However when I run this I get this test failure:

```
Moq.MockException

Expected invocation on the mock once, but was 0 times: manager => manager.AddDB(It.IsAny<KeynoteDB>(), It.IsAny<int>())

Performed invocations:

   Mock<IDBManager:1> (manager):

      IDBManager.KeynoteDBs
      IDBManager.IsLoading = True
      IDBManager.ActiveDB
      IDBManager.AddDB(KeynoteDB, -1)
      IDBManager.ActiveDB
      IDBManager.IsLoading = False

   at Moq.Mock.Verify(Mock mock, LambdaExpression expression, Times times, String failMessage)
   at Moq.Mock`1.Verify[TResult](Expression`1 expression, Func`1 times)
   at KMCore_Tests.AppCommandsTests.NewBlank_InvokesManagerAdd() in *my path*\AppCommandsTests.cs:line 140
```

Is it not listing that invocation 1 time in that list of invocations right in the middle?  How is it saying it has 0 invocations?  What am I missing?  I feel like I must be missing something dumb but I can't see it...

**EDIT**

Ok so this turned out to be a race condition issue because the commands are async. The command execution calls an async void method and it must have been hitting the assert before it hit the actual call (or at least that's all I can think of). I put in a await Task.Delay(500) after calling execute and before the assert and it is passing now.

Is there a better way to test this situation? The commands are essentially button handlers so I think async void is correct here from my understanding, but that means I can't await it in the unit test...

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should [avoid using async void anyway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void).

`async void` means fire and forget. In your case, you don't seem to want that because you need to wait until the async method is completed.

If you can't change the method signature, you could move the body of the `async void` method to a `Task` returning method.

So for example, change

```
public async void MyAsyncVoidMethod()
{
    await Task.Delay(500);

    MethodToBeCalled();
}
```

to

```
// Wait this task in unit test
public Task MyAsyncTask { get; private set; }

public async void MyAsyncVoidMethod()
{
    MyAsyncTask = MyAsyncTaskMethod();
    await MyAsyncTask;
}

public async Task MyAsyncTaskMethod()
{
    await Task.Delay(500);

    MethodToBeCalled();
}
```

Alternatively, if there is any event fired after the command is completed, you could also hook into one of those events to stay notified in your tests.

Comment: I know that async void is generally not recommended, but I thought the exception was 'top level' methods like button handlers that call async methods to get data and update the UI accordingly.  This isn't a button handler but it's an ICommand on the VM so it's basically doing the same thing.  In the main program execution I DO want it to fire and forget and then update the UI after it returns, etc.  However in the unit test I'm trying to validate that it calls the right methods to add things to the data model after it comes back. An execute method of an ICommand can't be async (AFAIK).

Comment: @sfaust I had to deal with a lot of similar scenarios in a UWP app where tons of `ICommand` is used. So I understand this. The point here is though it is fire-n-forget in the app, you still need to wait it in the test, so in total, you have hybrid fire-n-forget (which isn't really fire-n-forget). The way how I waited those actions are those I mentioned in the answer.

Comment: Ok so that code is in the regular code then?  Sorry I was reading it as in the test classes.  So basically my VM would have the main code in a Task method  but then the void method would just call the task method, correct?  And for the ICommand execution it would call the void but unit test would call the Task method and await it...  That makes sense and shouldn't be too hard, thank you!

Comment: @sfaust Yes, that's in your VM. The idea is you have to expose a task for the unit test to await on. Either getting the unit test to call the task returning method directly, or unit test to get the task via a property of your VM, or something else.